# F# constructor with <"string", str>

Tags: f#

[In this article](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) it shows how to use the `SqlCommandProvider` type. The sample code has this:

```
use cmd = new SqlCommandProvider<"
    SELECT TOP(@topN) FirstName, LastName, SalesYTD 
    FROM Sales.vSalesPerson
    WHERE CountryRegionName = @regionName AND SalesYTD > @salesMoreThan 
    ORDER BY SalesYTD
    " , connectionString>(connectionString)
```

what does the `<... ,...>` before the type constructor name mean and why the the
first parameter have to be a string literal? It looks like a generic but it's taking variables not types. The constructor seems to be taking in a connection string already in the `<>` section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angle brackets are the configuration for a type.
In your example, you are defining a type and creating an instance at the same type. It's clearer when the steps are separated.

Define a type.

```
type SalesPersonQuery = SqlCommandProvider<query, connectionString>
```

But to actually have an instance of the type you have to create it:

```
let command = new SalesPersonQuery()
```

Now you can use the `command.Execute()` rather then `SalesPersonQuery.Execute()`.

The reason there is a constructor is because later on (at run-time) you can change the connection string to a different then the one provided in the definition, so for instance:

```
let command = new SalesPersonQuery(differentConnectionString)
```

You can find that in [the documentation](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/) in configuration section:

> Connection string can be overridden at run-time via constructor optional parameter

First parameter can be a path to a SQL script or a SQL query. I suppose that's the reason it's a string: how else would you like to define a SQL query?

Again, from the documentation:

> Command text (sql script) can be either literal or path to *.sql file

Comment: is there any way I can make the type with a variable query? I would like to take in the query as a parameter.

Comment: I don't think so. Or at least I didn't see such an option in the documentation. I suppose you may try to have a mutable variable to manipulate that (I didn't try that, so you have to test if it's possible at all). But the you loose the advantages of having immutable values like no need for locking in multi-threaded environment.